# How to mouse click an object in scene view to select it from editor

Tags: unity

I have several game objects with colliders in my game. I have enabled `Always Show Colliders` to keep all of them visible in my scene view. Because the objects are a lot, selecting them from the hierarchy window is a bit cumbersome and really slowing down my workflow. How can I select an object by left mouse clicking on it  in the scene view of an editor?

Comment: Do you mean in the game view? The scene view should be selectable by default.

Comment: @Stephan No, if I understand your question well. I just want to be able to select game objects using the left mouse click in scene view when the game is not running.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be able to select colliders without adding any sort of mesh to them, then you can call an icon draw `OnDrawGizmos()` on a script and just add it to whatever you want to be drawn:

using System.Collections;

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class DrawIcon : MonoBehaviour {
    void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
        Gizmos.DrawIcon(transform.position, "Collider Gizmo.tiff", true);
    }
}
```

You can also then select a shape / color combo from the gizmos menu for `DrawIcon` in this case.

[image]

Clicking on it will select the relevant object:

[image]
Experiment with the code to customize it.

Comment: You can also set this up via the object's inspector if you don't want to add an extra script to each object.